# Rails 4 sending email to other users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I'm trying to create a form where the users are able to send the email to other users. When the users click on the 'link_to' email they are sent to contact form where they can contact each other. It's working fine except I don't know how to set 'default to' dynamically in user_mailer.rb.

I want the user to be able to send to whichever email link they click on. So how do I make default to method dynamic?

user.html.erb

```
<% if user.email.present? %>
    <b>Email:</b>
     <%= link_to "email", contact_path %>
<% end %>
```

user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default to: #user email

  def contact_email(name, email, body)
      @name = name
      @email = email
      @body = body

      mail(from: email, subject: '')
  end
end
```

contact.html.erb

```
<div class="container-content">
    <div class="container">
        <%= form_tag(send_mail_path) do %>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= label_tag 'name', 'Name' %>
                <%= text_field_tag 'name', nil, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Your Name' %>
            </div>
           <div class="form-group">
               <%= label_tag 'email', 'Email' %>
               <%= email_field_tag 'email', nil, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Your Email Address' %>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
               <%= label_tag 'comments', 'Comments' %>
               <%= text_area_tag 'comments', nil, class: 'form-control', rows: 4, placeholder: 'Comments...' %>
           </div>
           <%= submit_tag nil, class: 'btn btn-default btn-about pull-right' %>
       <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

user_controller.rb

```
 def send_mail
    name = params[:name]
    email = params[:email]
    body = params[:comments]
    UserMailer.contact_email(name, email, body).deliver_now
    redirect_to contact_path, notice: 'Message sent'
  end
```

Comment: In your `user_mailer.rb` just add `.deliver`, like `mail(from: email, subject: '').deliever`

Comment: I just edited my question, i got that in the controller

Comment: I can't see a way to set a value for `default to:` as the emails are dynamic. And if I'm not wrong the value for `default to:` should be static.

Comment: I want to do do something like default to: user.email but at the moment I can only pass a string value.

Comment: So the `user.email` is the value you want to pass to the receiver email right?

Comment: Ya so when the user fill and submits the form the email goes to that 'user.email'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see a way to set a value for `default to:` as the receiver email changes for different users(ie., they are dynamic). And if I'm not wrong the value for `default to:` should be static.

> I want the user to be able to send to whichever email link they click
>   on

Instead change your code to below

```
<% if user.email.present? %>
  <b>Email:</b>
  <%= link_to "email", contact_path(to_email: user.email) %> #pass an extra parameter
<% end %>
```

And in the `form`, make a ***hidden field*** like below

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'to_email', params[:to_email] %>
```

So now you can access it like `params[:to_email]` in the controller action.

```
def send_mail
  name = params[:name]
  email = params[:email]
  body = params[:comments]
  to_email = params[:to_email]
  #pass to_email as argument to this method
  UserMailer.contact_email(name, email, body, to_email).deliver_now
  redirect_to contact_path, notice: 'Message sent'
end
```

And finally the mailer method will be like below

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def contact_email(name, email, body, to_email)
    @name = name
    @email = email
    @body = body

    mail(from: email, subject: '', to: to_email)
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome bro looks like it worked but is there a way to hide the email in the params?

Comment: Actually this is what i get, mail to is blank so don't think it sent the mail `Sent mail to  (2.5ms)
Date: Tue, 27 Oct 2015 12:28:20 +0000
From: me@me.com`

Comment: I don't want to show the email address in the params. Is there any way to do that? Thanks

Comment: @Ray Try putting `config.filter_parameters += [:to_email]` in `application.rb`, restart the server and check.

Comment: it's still showing the email in the params although I get this in the log  `Parameters: {"to_email"=>"[FILTERED]"}`

Comment: @Ray Ofcourse that is what expected. Now it is not showing the email address right. `[FILTERED]` means it is encoded.

Comment: @ray oh ok. I don't know how to hide it in the url. You can ask another question regarding this, so that you can get answer.

Comment: Cheers appreciate your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93499/discussion-between-ray-and-pavan).

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use `default to` and write your mailer like that:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def contact_email(name, email, body, user)
      @name = name
      @email = email
      @body = body

      mail(from: email, to: user.email, subject: '')
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**

user.html.erb

```
<% if user.email.present? %>
    <b>Email:</b>
     <%= link_to "email", contact_path(user: user) %>
<% end %>
```

user_controller.rb

```
def send_mail
    name = params[:name]
    email = params[:email]
    body = params[:comments]
    user = params[:user]
    UserMailer.contact_email(name, email, body, user).deliver_now
    redirect_to contact_path, notice: 'Message sent'
  end
```

Comment: You also need to show the OP how the user.email can be accessed in the mailer method. Your current code results in an error.

Comment: Ya it doesnt know what user is

Comment: @Ray have you defined a method that accesses the current user object? Something like `current_user`  in your model `User`?

Comment: I tried to create a helper method `def send_to @users.each do |user| user.email end end` and pass it to the default to, but maybe i'm doing something wrong its not working

Comment: Can you pass the user to which you want to send an email like that `contact_email(name, email, body, user)`?

Comment: This is wrong! You are sending a email to the `current_user` itself instead the mail needs to send to different users.

Comment: No! You are missing the main point. `user.email` is in loop. It means the value for `user.email` differs for different users. You are sending a static value as `current_user.email` which is wrong.

Comment: I really don't see the difference. You pass to `contact_path` just the email of a user while I'm passing the whole object `user` and after that accessing its `email` field.